# How do I print out a tcl proc?

Tags: tcl, redefinition, proc-object

Given a simple tcl proc like

```
proc foo {a b} {puts "$a $b"}
```

What tcl command can I use to print out the procedure `foo` ... that is I want the *text* of the proc back ...

For instance:

```
% proc foo {a b} {puts "$a $b"}
% foo a b
  a b

% puts $foo
  can't read "foo": no such variable
```

how do I get `foo {a b} {puts "$a $b"}` back?

Answer (score 8):

```
% proc foo {a b} {puts "$a $b"}
% info body foo
puts "$a $b"
% info args foo
a b
```

For more goodies, reread info(n).

Answer (score 7):

@Henry, it's a bit more complicated than that if any arguments have default values:

```
proc foo {a {b bar}} {
    puts "$a $b"
}

proc info:wholeproc procname {
    set result [list proc $procname]
    set args {}
    foreach arg [info args $procname] {
        if {[info default $procname $arg value]} {
            lappend args [list $arg $value]
        } else {
            lappend args $arg
        }
    }
    lappend result [list $args]
    lappend result [list [info body $procname]]
    return [join $result]
}

info:wholeproc foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TclX's showproc:

```
package require Tclx
showproc foo
```